# Javascript output issue when parsing mysql timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp

I'm attempting to display how much time is left, based on a mysql timestamp. For some reason the output is -1 days, 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update(datetime = "2021-07-15 20:24:42") {
    timeleft = new Date(datetime);
    now = new Date();
    secs = (timeleft - now) / 1000;
    days    = Math.floor(secs / (3600 * 24));
    hours   = Math.floor((secs - (days * (3600 * 24)))/3600);
    minutes = Math.floor((secs - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    seconds = Math.floor(secs - (days * (3600 * 24)) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60));
    if (seconds < 0) {
        days = 0;
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
    }
    return  days+' days, '+ hours+' hours, '+minutes+' minutes, '+seconds+' seconds';
}
// time is pulled from database, but plugged in manually
member = Date("06-08-21 16:06:37");
alert("Left: "+update(member));
</script>
```

Any info would be appreciated

Comment: What is the date format in your database? is it DD-MM-YY or YYYY-MM-DD? `member` suggest it's the first, and `datetime` suggests it's the later. Neither of these formats are suitable for javascript `Date()`, you'll need convert it into proper format first.

Comment: You can use the Constructor function of `Date` like `new Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use `new Date()` to create a new instance and pass a valid date.

**2)** You are using `dd-mm-yy` format so you should make it valid because if you pass it directly then it will convert the date

```
member = new Date(dateString); // 2021-06-08T10:36:37.000Z
```

i.e Date is `08`, month = `06`, So you have to swap the date and month value before getting the date instance from `new Date()`

```
const dateString = "06-08-21 16:06:37".replace(
  /(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/,
  `$2-$1-$3`
);
```

```js
function update(datetime = "2021-07-15 20:24:42") {
  timeleft = new Date(datetime);
  now = new Date();
  secs = (timeleft - now) / 1000;
  days = Math.floor(secs / (3600 * 24));
  hours = Math.floor((secs - days * (3600 * 24)) / 3600);
  minutes = Math.floor((secs - days * (3600 * 24) - hours * 3600) / 60);
  seconds = Math.floor(secs - days * (3600 * 24) - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60);
  if (seconds < 0) {
    days = 0;
    hours = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 0;
  }
  return (
    days +
    " days, " +
    hours +
    " hours, " +
    minutes +
    " minutes, " +
    seconds +
    " seconds"
  );
}
// time is pulled from database, but plugged in manually
const dateString = "06-08-21 16:06:37".replace(
  /(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/,
  `$2-$1-$3`
);
member = new Date(dateString);
console.log("Left: " + update(member));
```